# VBA UserForm Multiple Dependent Dynamic ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, dependencies, userform

Basically I am trying to create multiple dependent dynamic Combo Boxes on a UserForm as it pulls the values from a LookupList Worksheet as seen below

[LookupList Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nzPp.png)

How it should work:

```
ComboBox1 would list the company
ComboBox2 is dependent on ComboBox1
ComboBox3 is dependent on ComboBox2
```

Example:

```
ComboBox1: Company = Mercedes
ComboBox2: Mercedes Model = A Class
ComboBox3: A Class Model = AMG
```

I have tried the code below but got stuck on ComboBox2

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'dynamically call ComboBox1 when form initialize
With Worksheets("LookupList")
ComboBox1.List = .Range("A2:A" & .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim index As Integer

'list ComboBox1 and look for dependency
index = ComboBox1.ListIndex
ComboBox2.Clear
ComboBox3.Clear

'call values in ComboBox2
Select Case index
Case Is = 0
'Calls Mercedes Car Model contents dynamically
With Worksheets("LookupList")
ComboBox2.List = .Range("C2:C" & .Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

Case Is = 1
'Calls BMW Car Model contents dynamically
With Worksheets("LookupList")
ComboBox2.List = .Range("G2:G" & .Range("g" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

End Select
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

Dim index As Integer
Dim verify_data As Long

index = ComboBox2.ListIndex

verify_data = ComboBox2.ListIndex

'Calls values in ComboBox3
Select Case index

If verify_data = 0 Then
'If Mercedes A Class Model is selected from ComboBox2, list A Class model types
Case Is = 0
With Workseets("LookupList")
ComboBox3.List = .Range("D2:D" & .Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

End If
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I have found a way now but it is the long way as shown in code below:

Comment: (If you have something that is broadly an answer, then please post as a self-answer, rather than merging it into the question. I've moved it for you just now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I managed to resolve my own issue as shown in code below. If anyone has a shorter method, please feel free to share.

```
  Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

  Dim index As Integer

  'list ComboBox2 and look for dependency
   index = ComboBox2.ListIndex
   ComboBox3.Clear

   If Me.ComboBox2.Value = "A Class" Then
   With Worksheets("LookupLists")
   ComboBox3.List = .Range("D2:D" & .Range("d" & 
   Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

   End With
   End If

   If Me.ComboBox2.Value = "B Class" Then
    With Worksheets("LookupLists")
    ComboBox3.List = .Range("E2:E" & .Range("e" & 
    Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

    End With
    End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to shorten the code is to refactor it with better syntax and assign each lookup list to a named range.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

  Dim index As Integer

  'list ComboBox2 and look for dependency
   index = ComboBox2.ListIndex
   ComboBox3.Clear

  Dim whichName as String

  Select Case index
      Case "A Class": whichName = "aClass" 'assumed named range scoped to worksheet
      Case "B Class": whichName = "bClass" 'assumed named range scoped to worksheet
  End Select

  ComboBox3.List = Worksheets("LookupLists").Range(whichName).Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = Worksheets("LookupList")
    With Ws
        ComboBox1.List = .Range("A2:A" & .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngT As Range, rngHead As Range
    Set Ws = Worksheets("LookupList")
    Set rngHead = Ws.Range("a1", "i1")


    ComboBox2.Clear
    ComboBox3.Clear

    Set rngT = rngHead.Find(ComboBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)
    If Not rngT Is Nothing Then
        ComboBox2.List = Ws.Range(rngT.Offset(1, 0), rngT.End(xlDown)).Value
    End If


End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngT As Range, rngHead As Range
    Set Ws = Worksheets("LookupList")
    Set rngHead = Ws.Range("a1", "i1")

    ComboBox3.Clear
    If ComboBox2.Value <> "" Then
        Set rngT = rngHead.Find(ComboBox2.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)
        If Not rngT Is Nothing Then
            ComboBox3.List = Ws.Range(rngT.Offset(1, 0), rngT.End(xlDown)).Value
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```